# mvn tomcat:run - how do I edit server.xml?

Tags: java, tomcat, server.xml

I want to run "mvn tomcat:run" from the command line, but how can I edit the server.xml to set maxHttpHeaderSize="65536" in the connectors? Or can I configure the connectors in the pom.xml?

Cheers

Nik

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, after doing some research, I don't think there's a way to edit server.xml's connectors.  `mvn tomcat:run` uses an embedded Tomcat.

Unless someone finds something, it seems like your best bet will be to move to the [maven cargo plugin](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Installer) and ZIP up your own Tomcat installation with your custom `server.xml`.

```
<cargo containerId="tomcat7x" [...]>
  <zipUrlInstaller
      installUrl="file://tomcat-custom.zip",
      installDir="target/installs"/>
  [...]
</cargo>
```

Or something of the sort...

Comment: It seems you're right, there is no way to do that at the moment other than rolling my own hack, such as through the cargo plugin.

Answer (score 8):

The org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin will let you set the path to the server.xml file in the configuration section:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <serverXml>path_to_server_xml_file</serverXml>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have been experimenting with using the serverXml parameter for the `tomcat:run` goal (http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2/tomcat6-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html#serverXml).

The following `server.xml` seems to run with no errors, but without a `Context` element it does not load the webapp.  I think if I copied my `Context` element from src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.xml to inside the `Host` element, it might work just fine:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Server port="-1" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
    <Service name="Catalina">
        <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" />
        <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
            <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps">
            </Host>
        </Engine>
    </Service>
</Server>
```

To run with this server, I pass the serverXml as a property on the Maven command line:

```
mvn -Dmaven.tomcat.serverXml=src/main/resources/server.xml tomcat:run
```

The goal might have to be `tomcat6:run` if you are using a version of the plugin that supports both Tomcat 6 and 7.

Answer (score 1):

see http://docs.codehaus.org/display/CARGO/Custom+File+Configurations

i *think* you can do it like this and place your custom server.xml in your project:

```xml
<configuration>
    <type>standalone</type>
    <configfiles> 
        <configfile> 
            <file>${basedir}/src/main/resources/server.xml</file> 
            <todir>conf</todir> 
        </configfile> 
    </configfiles> 
</configuration>
```

and use default cargo server.xml as a template to get property replacement:

```xml
<Server port="@cargo.rmi.port@" shutdown="SHUTDOWN" debug="@catalina.logging.level@">

  <Service name="Catalina" debug="@catalina.logging.level@">

    <Connector port="@cargo.servlet.port@"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
        enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
        connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true"
        scheme="@cargo.protocol@" secure="@catalina.secure@"
        debug="@catalina.logging.level@"
        emptySessionPath="@catalina.connector.emptySessionPath@"
        URIEncoding="@catalina.servlet.uriencoding@" />

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port @cargo.tomcat.ajp.port@ -->
    <Connector port="@cargo.tomcat.ajp.port@" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />

    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="@cargo.hostname@" 
        debug="@catalina.logging.level@">

      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MemoryRealm" />

      <!-- Note: There seems to be a bug in Tomcat 5.x if the debug attribute 
           is present. Ideally we would have written:
               debug="@catalina.logging.level@"
           However, doing this result in a NullPointerException in 
           ExpandWar.java at line 145. -->
      <Host name="@cargo.hostname@" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true"
          autoDeploy="true" xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

        <!-- Contexts to explicitely point to where the wars are located -->
        @tomcat.webapps@

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
            directory="logs" prefix="@cargo.hostname@_access_log." suffix=".txt"
            pattern="common" resolveHosts="false"/>

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```